# Non-serious book about children selected to be heroes by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking this book I read 5-10 years ago (I read a Finnish version but think it was a translation from English, I think the author had an English name). I think it is intended for children or teenagers.

- The main character is a human kid transported with other children and some adults to an alien space station in order to be trained as a hero for a fight against a vaguely detailed threat in space.
- The book has a very non-serious, silly and even childish tone. I can't remember exactly, but the threat they were fighting against sounded very absurd.
- The book focuses on interaction between the main character and other kids. In the end the main character is sent to fight the threat that is left vague. I think that they selected only some kids to go fighting.
- I can remember one detail that maybe helps. The aliens have a saying that contains the word *'rikkaus'* (wealth). The main character and some adult human discover that the saying is likely corrupted and it should be *'rakkaus'* (love). The aliens appear to not have the concept of love. As the book is probably translated, the original word play is likely different but similar.
- The space station had a place that in my mind was a kind of bridge over black void. I'm not sure it was described as such, but that is how I imagined it. The characters could go to the place and get a mystical experience. I think the main character heard about the saying in that place, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, fergusq! Did it seem to be a translation, or was it by a Finnish author? See [this great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help making this question even better!